# Google Cloud Resource Manager API - grant owner role to a user

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-cloud-platform

I am using [Google Cloud Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/) with Service Account authorization in Google Apps Script. In the program I am interested in updating the roles of a Developer Console Project.

Specifically, I am trying to change Developer Console project's owner to editor and another user as owner. This, I believe in terms of HTTP Request payload would look like:

```
// before (taken from response of getIamPolicy REST call)
{
    "bindings": [{
            "role": "roles/owner",
            "members": ["user:abc@my-google-domain.com"]
     }],
    "version": "0",
    "etag": "acbqwcada="
}

// after (modified policy) used in setIamPolicy REST call
{
    "bindings": [{
            "role": "roles/owner",
            "members": ["user:def@my-google-domain.com"]
     },
     {
            "role": "roles/editor",
            "members": ["user:abc@my-google-domain.com"]
     }],
    "version": "0",
    "etag": "acbqwcada="
}
```

Few things I observed:

- When changing current *owner* (user email) to *editor*  and adding *new owner* (user email) the API call is returning `SOLO_MUST_INVITE_OWNERS` error. Here, I am impersonating service account as initial owner of project with all necessary domain wide access
- However, when I do the same call in Google API explorer with same payload, its working fine!
- Google Cloud and Identity Management documentation seems confusing. It says in one point `"Cloud Resource Manager IAM methods only support granting the owner role to user and serviceAccount"` while in another point `"A user cannot be granted owner access using setIamPolicy(). The user must be granted the owner role using the Cloud Platform Console and he must explicitly accept the invitation."` -- I am wondering is there any other way to set policies other than setIamPolicy()?

Answer (score 2):

The Cloud Resource Manager API does not support adding an owner via `setIamPolicy`, [see the documentation on `setIamPolicy`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/setIamPolicy):

> To be added as an owner, a user must be invited via Cloud Platform
>   console and must accept the invitation.

After you've invited `def@my-google-domain.com` and they've accepted (they'll appear as an owner of the project in the Cloud Platform console, and also as a member of the `owner` binding returned by `getIamPolicy`) you can make the `setIamPolicy` call to make `abc@my-google-domain.com` an `editor`.

Comment: In this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/managing-policies) its mentioned "Cloud Resource Manager IAM methods only support granting the owner role to user and serviceAccount."

Comment: Only users or service accounts can be owners of a project (meaning only `"user:foo@..."` and `"serviceAccount:bar@..."` are supported members in the `owner` binding), but the CRM API does not currently support using `setIamPolicy` to make them owners. For now, the only way to do that is via the Cloud Platform console.