# Can't add user with "owner" role in GCP : via gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam

I wasn't able to add a new member in GCP (IAM) with the role `owner` using the gcloud command
The below command fails:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding linuxacademy-3 --member user:rohithmn3@gmail.com --role roles/owner
```

With the below Error/Exception:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.cloudresourcemanager.v1.ProjectIamPolicyError
  member: user:rohithmn3@gmail.com
  role: roles/owner
  type: SOLO_MUST_INVITE_OWNERS
```

But, the same command works well for other roles like: viewer, browser...! It just doesn't work for "owner".
Is there any alternative for this; if yes, How to add this in my Python Code.
Please help me here..!

Regards,
Rohith

Comment: Is the user an existing member with any other access/role?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298828/google-cloud-resource-manager-api-grant-owner-role-to-a-user

Comment: Both the case: new member or update the role of the existing member to "owner" - NOT WORKING..!

Comment: I saw that old ticket : But i didn't get the solution for my issue : Forgive me if i missed something..!

Comment: Follow the link to the docs in that ticket, specifically:
A user cannot be granted the owner role using setIamPolicy(). The user must be granted the owner role using the Cloud Platform Console and must explicitly accept the invitation.

Invitations to grant the owner role cannot be sent using setIamPolicy(); they must be sent only using the Cloud Platform Console.

What you are attempting is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Resource Manager API - grant owner role to a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298828/google-cloud-resource-manager-api-grant-owner-role-to-a-user)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot grant the owner role to a member for a project using the Cloud IAM API or the gcloud command-line tool. You can only add owners to a project using the Cloud Console. An invitation will be sent to the member via email and the member must accept the invitation to be made an owner of the project, [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#invitation_flow)

Comment: Is this going to be fixed?